# First boot for just assembled PC nothing on monitor

Tags: windows, boot, bios, desktop-computer

Just assembled PC, all fans are spinning, RAM is shining, but still don't have anything on my monitor.

I connect 24 pins to motherboard. My power supply have 8 pins for CPU, and mother board just 4. I parted 8 pins and connect just 4 to motheboard. My graphics card does not require power supply to be connected, so that 6+2 pins from power supply isn't connected to anything.

I don't have pins where to connect then on motherboard or on video card. I tried without video card to boot, but still nothing on monitor. Tried with different monitor still nothing on screen.

My components are:

- Motherboard: ASRock a320m DVS r4.0
- Power Supply: Cooler Master Elite V3 600w
- Graphics Card: GeForce gt1030
- CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 1600
- RAM: Kingston HyperX FURY 8gb cl16 3200mghz.

Do you have idea what is problem might be?

Comment: Is the monitor plugged into the graphics card? or to the motherboard?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the screen has power and is on -  then try to boot from a Live Disk like Knoppix this will enable you to track down if it is connection or configuration

Also before anything make sure the ram is seated on MOBO - loose ram can cause this sort of issue